# double loop matrix instead use of loop R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, apply

I'm new using apply/purrr functions. I don't know when and how use this functions. I have double loop for matrix and i want to avoid them. is there one way to do it? I have to do this operation (see code below)

```
NCols=4
NRows=4

set.seed(1234)
myMat<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
myMat

norm=matrix(0,NRows,NCols)

 for (i in 1:nrow(myMat)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(myMat)){
      norm[i,j] <- sum((myMat[i,]-myMat[j,])^2)
    }
  }
```

thanks

Use dist function for @markus it is faster way to do it.

Comment: @www sorry i forgot it. It's empty matrix. I updated code. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `dist` as it seems you seek to calculate the square of the euclidean distance.

```
dist(myMat, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE) ^ 2
#          1         2         3         4
#1 0.0000000 0.7408859 0.9713548 0.9768185
#2 0.7408859 0.0000000 0.8285694 0.1746331
#3 0.9713548 0.8285694 0.0000000 0.3690422
#4 0.9768185 0.1746331 0.3690422 0.0000000
```

Comment: This is impressive. Please see my `microbenchmark` in my answer. The `dist` function is much faster than other methods.

Comment: @www Thanks for the benchmark (+1). Yes, quite an improvement over OP's loops.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `expand.grid` to create all the combination of the indices, and then use `map2_dbl` to loop through all the combination and finally create a matrix.

```
library(purrr)

ind <- expand.grid(1:NRows, 1:NRows)

norm <- matrix(map2_dbl(ind$Var1, ind$Var2, ~sum((myMat[.x,] - myMat[.y,])^2)),
               NRows, NCols)
norm
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.7408859 0.9713548 0.9768185
# [2,] 0.7408859 0.0000000 0.8285694 0.1746331
# [3,] 0.9713548 0.8285694 0.0000000 0.3690422
# [4,] 0.9768185 0.1746331 0.3690422 0.0000000
```

Similar idea, but we can also use `Vectorize`.

```
myfun <- function(x, y) sum((myMat[x,] - myMat[y,])^2)
myfun_v <- Vectorize(myfun)

norm <- matrix(myfun_v(ind$Var1, ind$Var2), NRows, NCols)
norm
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.7408859 0.9713548 0.9768185
# [2,] 0.7408859 0.0000000 0.8285694 0.1746331
# [3,] 0.9713548 0.8285694 0.0000000 0.3690422
# [4,] 0.9768185 0.1746331 0.3690422 0.0000000
```

Here is the speed comprison for the current methods, inlcuding the `dist` function from the other answer.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(m1 = {ind <- expand.grid(1:NRows, 1:NRows);
                     matrix(map2_dbl(ind$Var1, ind$Var2, ~sum((myMat[.x,] - myMat[.y,])^2)),
                            NRows,NCols)},
               m2 = {ind <- expand.grid(1:NRows, 1:NRows);
                     myfun <- function(x, y) sum((myMat[x,] - myMat[y,])^2);
                     myfun_v <- Vectorize(myfun);
                     matrix(myfun_v(ind$Var1, ind$Var2), NRows, NCols)},
               m3 = {for (i in 1:nrow(myMat)){
                 for (j in 1:nrow(myMat)){
                   norm <- matrix(0, NRows, NCols);
                   norm[i,j] <- sum((myMat[i,]-myMat[j,])^2)
                 }}},
               m4 = {dist(myMat, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)^2}
               )

Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   m1  261.142  278.3625  310.1212  302.5230  323.8570   434.894   100  b 
   m2  200.997  238.7805  287.5953  259.5995  286.3305  2417.610   100  b 
   m3 4902.562 5369.8390 5725.5358 5578.2895 5717.8560 10317.123   100   c
   m4   16.451   22.6200   34.1653   32.9010   42.4110    81.222   100 a
```

Comment: @liguang It could be slower than `for loop` as `map_dbl` requires additional time to check if the output is numeric or not.

Comment: and is there one way to do it faster than loop?

Comment: @liguang Please see my updates. I don't think my methods are slower than the for-loop, but the `dist` function proposed by the others is much faster than my mehthod. Please consider to use the `dist` function.